# Hot Swap Disk With One Disk Failed and One Predictive Fail in Same Array

Tags: raid, hard-drive

I have a RAID 10 Array sitting on a HP Smart Array P410i controller. One disk has an error status and one has a predictive failure status. Is it safe to replace the predictive failure disk and then replace the errored disk?

Comment: Before you do *anything* else, ensure you have a good backup of all the data on that array.

Comment: yea, but is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Well you don't have much of a choice, do you? Get a good backup, then replace the drives, starting with the failed one, and pray that you don't have any additional failures during the rebuild.

Comment: Fair enough. 
I have a bunch of Windows VMs hosted on the array and they aren't backed up as they are just dev machines (but I really don't want to rebuild them). We are short of storage for them as well so I don't really have a backup option. I could purchase some storage but before I spend any money I just wanted to know if replacing the predictive disk was doable.

Comment: If you have the option, I'd shut down the operating system on this server so that all available IO can be dedicated to the rebuild process. This will also shorten the rebuild time.

Comment: Cheers, I'll do that.